# Unknown Malloc 16 Bytes instruments

Tags: instruments, xcode6.1

I am unable to identify the root cause for the below leak shown in the image. It is showing as Malloc 16 Bytes, how to resolve this memory leak.Any help could be appreciated

[image]

Comment: We can't identify the root cause either *because you didn't include any code*.

Comment: Aside: "snapshotting" (from the screen shot) - isn't that bad English?